# Get BigCommerce product option variantId

Tags: product, bigcommerce, variant

Need to be able to lookup a product's variantId to add to a a Custom Field for a cart api to add items to the shopping cart using one of these:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/storefront-cart-api/cart/postcarts
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/storefront-cart-api/cart/postcartscartiditems

Unable to find where this data exists without adding the variant to the cart and then getting cart data. Need an easier way for marketing team to be able to access.

Is this possible without an api call in the admin or product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like can now get it using this call:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/catalog/catalog-api/product-variants/getvariantsbyproductid

Comment: Yes, this is the v3 API I mentioned in my answer :) You can either get variants by product ID or include them as a subresource with all products. Apologies if I misunderstood your question--it sounded like you needed get variant IDs client-side since you're working with the storefront cart API.

Answer (score 1):

Today, we don't expose the v3 variant ID on the storefront, but we have updates coming soon that will allow you to get variant_id from the storefront API consumed by [Stencil utils](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/adding-event-hooks-to-your-theme/stencil-utils-api-reference#stencil-utils_product-attributes).

In the meantime, the best way to get the variant_id would be a server-side call to the [v3 API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/catalog/catalog-api/products/getproducts), or by retrieving the cart (as you mentioned):

`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/catalog/products?include=variants`

Comment: Accepting as this is the best we get for now.

Comment: @JoshuaFricke Wanted to post an update--we've deployed the change that adds v3 variant ID to the storefront product attributes API. Now, Stencil utils will return `"v3_variant_id"` in the response. Hope it helps!